# Sum cells if date is correct (SUMIF)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having a little problem with Google Sheets. My sheet looks like this:

```
A                       B              C
24.11.2014 07:30:12  Fruit            500   
24.11.2014 17:34:32  Meat             450 
25.11.2014 07:30:09  Blah            1000
25.11.2014 18:30:47  Blah             802
```

Now I want to add the numbers in C:C if the date equals `24.11.2014`. My first guess was using:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,">="&E2,C:C)
```

Where E2 = 24.11.2014

After messing around with it, it still gives me a parsing error. SUMIF usually works with Google Sheets.

Comment: Hi Rezin, your formula looks ok to me. If you have a parsing error, maybe you are on a locale that uses semi colons instead of comma's as argument separators ? Can you try =SUMIF(A:A;">="&E2;C:C)

Comment: Facepalm! You were 100% right. Thanks so much!

Comment: If you are looking for *the date equals 24.11.2014* then go one step further with `=sumifs(C:C,A:A,">="&E2, A:A, "<"&(E2+1))`.

Comment: You are welcome Rezin !

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest solution:

```
=SUMIF(A:A;"*"&E2&"*";C:C)
```

[image]

you sum the values in **C:C** if you find **E2** in **A:A**. and the result **950** in this example. Hope this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After changing to the right argument  separator (for the locale of the OP) the original formula seemed to work:

```
=SUMIF(A:A;">="&E2;C:C)
```